# Powershell to set GPO

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, gpo

I want to set the value of "Inclusion list for Moderate risk file Types" to enable and add a file extension to the list. The key exists in :

```
User Configuration>Administrative Templates>Windows Components>Attachment Manager
```

How can I use powershell to turn this on and off ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a GPO based on a registry key on a W2K8 R2 computer, the roadmap is the following

Import the Active-Directory module :

`Import-module activeDirectory`

Create a GPO and link it to an OU :

```
New-GPO -Name "MyGPO" | New-GPLink -target "ou=MyOU,dc=silogix,dc=fr" -LinkEnabled Yes"
```

Create the registry value :

```
Set-GPPrefRegistryValue -Name "MyGPO" -Context User -Action Create -Key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MyClef" -ValueName Value1 -Value Value2 -Type string
```

Comment: Thanks JPBlanc...I'll give that a shot and report back

Comment: It appears that the activeDirectory module requires the AD roles enabled on the server. So I ended up not going the GPO route and instead made changes to the registry via powershell. New-ItemProperty -name ModRiskFileTypes -propertyType string HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Associations -value "*.exe"  And to Remove  Remove-ItemProperty HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Associations ModRiskFileTypes