# How to get/set/update registry value through group policy cmdlet of Windows PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, windows-server, powershell-cmdlet, group-policy

I have configured the EventForwarding Manually but I was wondeing If I could do it programmatically and I came across the [Group Policy Cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461040) which seems to be the solution. Here is what I am trying to configure manually in the image below.

[image: Event Forwarding Policy Config]

When I run the **Get-GPO -all** cmdlet I don't see any GPOs related to Event Forwarding. However when I ran the **Get-GPResultantSetOfPolicy** with the specified path of an XML file, I got to see my configuration of the Subscription manager of the Event Forwarding.

Question 1: Why isn't the event forwarding policy shown in **Get-GPO -all** result?

Question 2: How to find out the GUID of the policy I need so I can use the **[Get-GPRegistryValue](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461040)**? besides providing the Key (which I was able to find and verfiy that it has my configuration that I have done through the gpedit.msc UI.

Question 3: How to figure out the display name of the policy in question? I tried the following:

```
PS C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions> Get-GPRegistryValue -Name SubscriptionManager -Key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies
\Microsoft\Windows\EventLog\EventForwarding\SubscriptionManager
```

Where I tried for the Name attribute different things like : "EventForwarding", "EventForward", "SubscriptionManager" and even "Configure target Subscription Manager".
And here is what I got :

```
***Get-GPRegistryValue : The command cannot be completed because a GPO that is named "SubscriptionManager" was not found
in the nfstest.stbtest.microsoft.com domain. Make sure that the GPO that is specified by the Name parameter exists in
the domain that is specified for the cmdlet. Then, run the command again.
Parameter name: Name
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-GPRegistryValue -Name SubscriptionManager -Key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\P ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Group...tryValueCommand:GetGPRegistryValueCommand) [Get-GPReg
   istryValue], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GpoWithNameNotFound,Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Commands.GetGPRegistryValueCommand***
```

Any Help regarding any of the three related questions would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**:

As you can see in the image below, when I manually configure taregt subscription manager, I get the key *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EventLog\EventForwarding\SubscriptionManager* in the registry. My question for now is simple, how can I do that with cmdlets? All what I tried so far didn't create that key for me in the registry , NOT the AD.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry not sure to understand what you do. Here is a full example :

```
PS C:\silogix> Import-Module grouppolicy
PS C:\silogix> New-GPO -Name "MyGPO" | New-GPLink -target "OU=SousMonou,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr" `
                       -linkenabled yes


GpoId       : f31df409-ca35-47cd-b699-52426e2bd196
DisplayName : MyGPO
Enabled     : True
Enforced    : False
Target      : OU=SousMonou,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr
Order       : 1



PS C:\silogix> get-gpo -all


DisplayName      : Default Domain Policy
DomainName       : dom.fr
Owner            : DOM\Admins du domaine
Id               : 31b2f340-016d-11d2-945f-00c04fb984f9
GpoStatus        : AllSettingsEnabled
Description      :
CreationTime     : 16/09/2010 21:07:03
ModificationTime : 09/09/2011 21:04:06
UserVersion      : AD Version: 0, SysVol Version: 0
ComputerVersion  : AD Version: 11, SysVol Version: 11
WmiFilter        :

DisplayName      : Default Domain Controllers Policy
DomainName       : dom.fr
Owner            : DOM\Admins du domaine
Id               : 6ac1786c-016f-11d2-945f-00c04fb984f9
GpoStatus        : AllSettingsEnabled
Description      :
CreationTime     : 16/09/2010 21:07:03
ModificationTime : 06/06/2012 17:58:00
UserVersion      : AD Version: 0, SysVol Version: 0
ComputerVersion  : AD Version: 4, SysVol Version: 4
WmiFilter        :

DisplayName      : MyGPO
DomainName       : dom.fr
Owner            : DOM\Admins du domaine
Id               : f31df409-ca35-47cd-b699-52426e2bd196
GpoStatus        : AllSettingsEnabled
Description      :
CreationTime     : 08/06/2012 07:04:16
ModificationTime : 08/06/2012 07:04:16
UserVersion      : AD Version: 0, SysVol Version: 0
ComputerVersion  : AD Version: 0, SysVol Version: 0

PS C:\silogix> Set-GPRegistryValue -Name "MyGPO" -Key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EventLog\EventForwarding\SubscriptionManager -value "Server=https://EVTCPT:5986/wsman/SubscriptionManager/WEC" -t
ype String

PS C:\silogix> Get-GPRegistryValue -name "MyGPO" -Key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EventLog\EventForwarding\SubscriptionManager"


KeyPath     : SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EventLog\EventForwarding\SubscriptionManager
FullKeyPath : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EventLog\EventForwarding\SubscriptionManager
Hive        : LocalMachine
PolicyState : Set
Value       : Server=https://EVTCPT:5986/wsman/SubscriptionManager/WEC
Type        : String
ValueName   : 1
HasValue    : True
```

So you can see it in `GPMC.MSC`.
[image]

Comment: I have edited my question. Hope it is clearer now. I was wondering , does that work when I set such a policy even though I see the gpedit.msc Subscription Manager disabled? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the computer on which you use gpedit is under the coverage of the policy? Do you verify that the policy is applied ?

Comment: yes I am sure I set up EventForwarding manually and it is forwarding events if that is what you mean. I just need to know how to do it using cmdlets only. Does your solution above work, does it forward events to the collector machine?

Comment: Is that how it should work? I cannot change the registry values at all?

Comment: If it works using manualy written GPOs, it works using programaticaly written GPOs.

Comment: I know but why is it not changing the reg value in regedit or changing the first view I showed you above? Do you know the answer of Question 1 above? Why is creating the policy manually (through gpedit by enabling does not show in the GPOs when I use Get-GPO -all)? That is what I need to know.

Comment: I guess the answer is her :http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978244 What I need is local group policy.

Comment: I am but I need it to apply to the local machine. This is why I asked why when I create a policy using New-GPO it doesn't show up in gpedit. And I still do not know why since this was my question.

Comment: Recursively run get-gpregistryvalue:  https://sdmsoftware.com/group-policy-blog/general-stuff/find-all-registry-settings-managed-in-a-gpo